# Sublime text custom build system for gulp

Tags: gulp, sublimetext3, build-process

I got my project set up so that if I'm in the root directory and run 'gulp' it does it's thing. I don't want to open cmd every time though, so I looked into how I can do it from sublime text. Seems like the "build system" is made for it. After some googling here's what I came up with.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "gulp",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
}
```

I figured that would do the trick, but when ever I try to "build" I just get the error:

```
C:\currently\open\file (1) : ==> Unable to parse line.: 
{ 
^ ERROR
```

So any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Why does it try to parse the file that is open instead of running "gulp" from the folder that I have opened?

Answer (score 7):

I use the following build system for Gulp:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gulp"],
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
}
```

Comment: This really helped me out too.